# How to render a view thats inside a subfolder

Tags: php, yii2

Just installed the yii2 framework and playing with it, but i cant seem to get it to work with files that are located inside a folder.

All other pages(index,contact,about,index etc) are inside the `views/site` folder, but I added a new folder to the `views` folder called `blog` which contains a new view called `index.php`.

folder structure:

```
project

- views
-- site
--- index.php
--- about.php
--- (more files)
-- blog
--- index.php


class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionBlog()
    {
        // not working
        return $this->render('blog/index');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the path simply no use to create the controller with name `Blog` specifically, just add

```
return $this->render('/blog/index')
```

inside your new action `actionBlog()` in the `SiteController`.

Just remember that if you are not following `Yii` convention of using the `controllers` and `view`, start the path with a trailing `/` when specifying the view, if you dont add the trailing slash it will try to find the path you specified in the render method inside the 
`views/site` directory and adding a trailing slash will search from the `views` root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 sets the view directory to controllers based on their names match. So you can have a controller named BlogController and then simply render the index view:

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function actionBlog() // OR public function actionIndex()
    {
        // not working
        return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 view paths are relative to the controller as @Saberi mentioned. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#named-views)

> If the view name starts with a single slash /, the view file path is
>   formed by prefixing the view name with the view path of the currently
>   active module. If there is no active module, @app/views/ViewName will
>   be used. For example, /user/create will be resolved into
>   @app/modules/user/views/user/create.php, if the currently active
>   module is user. If there is no active module, the view file path would
>   be @app/views/user/create.php.

So the best thing is to create a BlogController, however if you really need to, you can achieve this by rendering from the SiteController via `$this->render('/blog/index')` -- again, not really recommended -- or even by calling/redirecting to BlogController from SiteController, which also can get messy, but possible.